# I'm not able to render content, when I click on React Router Link

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react application. The problem which I m facing is that I'm not able to render content when I click on the Link.

Here my code:
In the index.js file, I have set the browserRouter and a Main component

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './Main';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Route, NavLink, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Main />
  </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Main.js
In Main.js, I have set the route paths. I have created PLPMenu and PDP components. Ideally, it should navigate from PLPMenu to PDP.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './components/topNavigation';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Banner from './components/Banner';
import PLPMenu from './components/PLPMenu';
import PDP from './components/PDP';
import Home from './components/Home';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Apparel/Girls/:subName/:id" component={PLPMenu} />
          <Route path="/Apparel/Girls/:fName/:id" component={PDP} />
          <Route path="/Banner" component={Banner} />
          <Route path="/Footer" component={Footer} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

PLPMenu.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from 'axios';

class PLPMenu extends Component {
  state = {
    shoeCategory: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let { subName, id } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(subName);
    console.log(id);

    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3030/category/` + id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.express.catalogEntryView);
        this.setState({
          shoeCategory: response.data.express.catalogEntryView
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { shoeCategory } = this.state;

    const picUrl = 'https://149.129.128.3:8443';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {shoeCategory &&
              shoeCategory.map(shoeList => {
                return (
                  <div key={shoeList.uniqueID} className="col-md-4">
                    <h2 key={shoeList.uniqueID} />

                    <img src={picUrl + shoeList.thumbnail} />
                    <Link
                      to={`/Apparel/Girls/${shoeList.name}/${
                        shoeList.uniqueID
                      }`}
                    >
                      <p className="pdp">{shoeList.name}</p>
                    </Link>
                    <p>
                      Price : {shoeList.price[0].value}{' '}
                      {shoeList.price[0].currency}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PLPMenu;
```

PDP.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from 'axios';

class PDP extends Component {
  state = {
    pdpCategory: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let { fName, id } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(fName);
    console.log(id);

    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3030/category/` + id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.express.catalogEntryView);
        this.setState({
          pdpCategory: response.data.express.catalogEntryView
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { pdpCategory } = this.state;

    const picUrl = 'https://149.129.128.3:8443';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {pdpCategory &&
              pdpCategory.map(pdpList => {
                return (
                  <div key={pdpList.uniqueID} className="col-md-4">
                    <h2 key={pdpList.uniqueID} />

                    <img src={picUrl + pdpList.thumbnail} />
                    <p>
                      Price : {pdpList.price[0].value}{' '}
                      {pdpList.price[0].currency}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PDP;
```

As you can see from my screenshot below, 
[image]

When I click on the picture, it should take me to the PDP page. But, in my case, only the URL gets changed, the content doesn't get rendered.

Can someone please help me with this. I got stuck and not able to proceed further.
In my console browser window, all I'm getting is this
[image]

Comment: Which version of react router are you using? v4?

Comment: yes v4 @c-chavez...Only the url is changed in the router...but content doesnt render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have two same looking route

```
<Route path="/Apparel/Girls/:subName/:id" component={PLPMenu} />
<Route path="/Apparel/Girls/:fName/:id" component={PDP} />
```

React-router will always return first matched route in `Switch`. So in your case any route `/Apparel/Girls/xyz/abc` will match the first component `PLPMenu`.

Because from `url` you wont be able to differentiate these two routes.

So when you are going in specific product by clicking on it will always render `PLPMenu` and in product's case you wont get any data so its rendering empty.

You will needs to change route something as below or as per your project :

```
<Route path="/Apparel/Girls/Category/:id" component={PLPMenu} />
<Route path="/Apparel/Girls/Product/:id" component={PDP} />
```

Comment: I have changed but it's still showing blank. Will you take a look in my code sandbox

Comment: Make sure your linking to correct link in `<Link
                      to={'/Apparel/Girls/Product/${
                        shoeList.uniqueID
                      }'}`

Comment: put some static content in file and see if there is problem with data or component it self not loading.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in how you are determining when to render `pdpCategory` in your `PDP` component. You are asking if it exists and then mapping it's content, but the axios request is async and it's filling your info afterwards. Since in the state it is being initialised as an empty array, it will always try to map the empty array, and since it's empty, nothing will be rendered. Also, set the state in the constructor.

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t
>   need to implement a constructor for your React component.
>
> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.
>
> Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:
>
> Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state. Binding
>   event handler methods to an instance. You should not call setState()
>   in the constructor(). Instead, if your component needs to use local
>   state, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the
>   constructor

So, you should either:

1. initialise `pdpCategory` as null or different than an array, and validate it has values
2. Handle the rendering of `pdpCategory` depending on another state variable

Using the first approach:

```
class PDP extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pdpCategory: null
        };
      }

    render() {
    const { pdpCategory } = this.state;

    const picUrl = 'https://149.129.128.3:8443';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {pdpCategory && pdpCategory.length > 0
              pdpCategory.map(pdpList => {
                return (
                  <div key={pdpList.uniqueID} className="col-md-4">
                    <h2 key={pdpList.uniqueID} />

                    <img src={picUrl + pdpList.thumbnail} />
                    <p>
                      Price : {pdpList.price[0].value}{' '}
                      {pdpList.price[0].currency}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to use the second approach, just create a new variable in the state called something like `dataLoaded`, initialise it as false, after the axios call set it to true and then in the render check for it in:

```
{pdpCategory && dataLoaded &&
    pdpCategory.map(pdpList => {
    ...
```

This should help you with your issue.

Comment: I have tried using the second approach, still it's showing blank. Will you guide me a little.

Comment: It also seems that you are using the same endpoint for both components (`get(`http://localhost:3030/category/` + id)`). Do you have a different one for your PDP component? maybe something like `get(`http://localhost:3030/item/` + id)`?

Comment: I have changed the endpoint....and have used your code. It's working now

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya Perfect! Always remember to mark the most useful answer as the correct one. Cheers!